# Ruby non-greedy modifier did not apply?

Tags: regex, ruby, regex-greedy

I have a regexp with a non-greedy modifier which does not seem to work. I have tried so many variations of the regexp and various other ways I could think of, without success, that I am losing my head

I want to remove all the empty strings embedded in the string `s` below. With my regexp I was expecting to remove all the things that matched something=""

```
s = 'a,b="cde",f="",g="hi",j=""'

puts s; puts s.gsub( /,.+?="",?/ , "," ).chomp(','); nil
```

Expected:

```
a,b="cde",g="hi"
```

What I get:

```
a,g="hi"
```

Why isn't the `.+?` non greedy in the `gsub` regexp below?

It works if I constrain the `.` to a set of characters `[\w\d_-]`, but that forces me to do assumptions:

```
puts s; puts s.gsub( /,[\w\d_-]+?=""/ , "" ).chomp(','); nil

# outputs:
a,b="cde",f="",g="hi",j=""
a,g="hi"
```

It also works if I do some sort of negative lookup like:

```
puts s; puts s.gsub( /,.+?="",?/ , "," ).chomp(','); nil

# outputs:
a,b="cde",f="",g="hi",j=""
a,g="hi"
```

But still I do not understand why it did not work in the first case.

Comment: You may be thinking that the first part of `/,.+?="",?/` means "match a comma followed by one or more characters other than an equals sign", but you can't stop there because the regex requires that the equals sign must be immediately followed by two double quotes (and then optionally a comma). Recall what is meant by a non-greedy match: ["By contrast, lazy matching makes the minimal amount of matches necessary for overall success."](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Regexp.html). I think you may have overlooked "necessary for overall success".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex matches from left to right. Your regex `,.+?="",?` matches the first comma in the string `a,b="cde",f="",g="hi",j=""`, the one between `a` and `b`. Then it tries to find `=""` that exists after the `,g` so you get the actual result.

What you want is: `,[^=]+?="",?` that matches 1 or more any character that is not an equal sign before `=""` and you'll get `a,b="cde",g="hi"` as result.